# Is there a way to let Ansible deal with the file:// protocol to download files?

Tags: ansible

I need to download files from a network share that has not HTTP nor FTP server running.

I tried with the *unarchive* and *copy* modules but it appears they don't support the `file` descriptor.

```
- name: Copy file from server
  copy:
    src: file://path/to/file.ext
    dest: /path/to/destination/file.ext
```

Is there a way to use the `file` protocol to download files from remote locations with Ansible (2.x)?

Comment: Couldn't you use the `command` module as a workaround?

Comment: @Railslide I could but I would like to use a module if possible

Answer (score 1):

I think the module you are searching for is `fetch`:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html

**Example**

```
- name: Get file from server
  fetch:
    src: /path/on/your/managed/machine
    dest: /local/path/to/file
```

Don't forget to use the full path to file